# WCF: IErrorHandler implementation not providing generic fault as specified

Tags: c#, wcf, ierrorhandler

I have implemented `ProvideFault` method of `IErrorHandler` interface as follows:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception ex, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
    responseModel.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

    FaultException<ResponseModel> faultEx;

    if (ex is FaultException<ResponseModel>)
    {
        return;
    }
    ServerCoreException coreException = ex as ServerCoreException;
    if (coreException != null)
    {
        ServerCoreException serverCoreException = coreException;
        faultEx = new FaultException<ResponseModel>(responseModel,
        new FaultReason(serverCoreException.Message),
        new FaultCode(serverCoreException.ErrorCode.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        faultEx = new FaultException<ResponseModel>(responseModel,
        new FaultReason(ex.Message),
        new FaultCode("-1"));
    }
    MessageFault msgFault = faultEx.CreateMessageFault();
    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, msgFault, faultEx.Action);
}
```

Then I add this implementation to every `ChannelDispatcherBase` in another implementation of `IServiceBehavior` called `GlobalErrorBehaviorAttribute`. My service implementations are decorated with this attribute and also have `FaultContractAttribute` as:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(ResponseModel), Name = "ServiceFaultException",
             Namespace = "http://ws.net.core/base/model")]
```

But test for methods inside service implementation are always failing complaining that the received fault is not of type `FaultException<ResponseModel>` but `FaultException` instead:

```
Assert.That(() => client.CreateVersion(request), Throws.TypeOf<FaultException<ResponseModel>>());
```

Why am I receiving `FaultException` instead of `FaultException<ResponseModel>` in client side?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588320/client-will-not-catch-generic-faultexception-t-only-faultexception

Comment: @RicardoPeres Thanks, but I already have in my code fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, msgFault, faultEx.Action); as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Has ResponseModel [DataContract] applited?

Comment: @Maximus Thanks for your time. Yes, I have the DataContract attribute set.